# Problem understanding a question (picked from **Set Theory and Matrices** by I.Kaplansky)

Tags: equivalence-relations

Suppose that a set X is expressed as a union of disjoint subsets. For $j, \, k \in X$ define $j \sim k$ that $j$ and $k$ lie in the same subset. Prove equivalency.

How do I start?

---

My attempt:

I would write $X=\bigcup_{i}A_i$ [where $A_j \neq A_k$] [fault]

Then, I would let $B \subset X$. Therefore, if $k$ or $j$ $\in B$ then they would also have to lie within $X$. But hereafter, I am stuck...

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Do you know which 3 properties of the relation you need to check/prove to make sure that it is an equivalence relation?

Comment: Reflexivity, Symmetri and transitivity, right?

Comment: So why don't you check the three one by one?

Comment: @Carl Yes! Can you tackle them in that order (transitivity is usually and in this case the hardest)

Comment: There's a [partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set) of $X$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to start.  First, write down the properties you need to show about $\sim$:

1. $\sim$ is **reflexive**: That is, $x \sim x$ for all $x \in X$.
2. $\sim$ is **symmetric**: That is, whenever $x_1,x_2 \in X$ satisfy $x_1 \sim x_2$, then also $x_2 \sim x_1$.
3. $\sim$ is **transitive**: That is, whenever $x_1,x_2,x_3 \in X$ satisfy $x_1 \sim x_2$ and $x_2 \sim x_3$, then also $x_1 \sim x_3$.

Now prove them.  The first two are really just translations of the definition of $\sim$. 
 The hardest is transitivity, and for it you need to use the fact that the sets in the partition given are not just *disjoint* but *pairwise disjoint.*

Comment: Okey, here is my attempt: *Reflexitivity*. Let $x \in X$ and therefore $x \in A_1 \cup A_2 \cdots$. Because all $A_i$ are disjoint, that means that $(x \in A_1)\vee(x \in A_2)\cdots$.

Comment: *Symmetry* Let $x_1$ and $x_2$ $\in X$. Because all $A_i$ are disjoint, that means that $[(x_1\in A_1)\vee (x_1 \in A_2)\cdots]\wedge[(x_2 \in A_1)\vee(x_2\in A_2)\cdots]$ @Matthew here I am stuck, I don't know if I am on the right track or not

Comment: You're going too fast.  Don't overload on the notation.  For reflexivity: Let $x \in X$; you want to show that $x \sim x$.  In other words, you want to show that $x$ and $x$ belong to the same part of the same subset.  Not much more to say than that, is there?

Comment: For symmetry: Let $x$ and $y$ be elements of $X$ such that $x \sim y$.  That is, $x$ and $y$ both belong to the same subset $A$.  Do $y$ and $x$ belong to the same subset?

Comment: Okey, I have got it now. Thank you for your answer